# Загрузка файла в рамках REST-JSON концепции

Tags: http, rest

Делаем REST-сервис, в качестве транспорта используется JSON (если требуется конкретика - сервис делается на Java/Spring). Возникла необходимость загружать файлы, и я не понимаю, как правильно должен выглядеть запрос. В данный момент все данные передаются JSON-массивом внутри тела запроса без каких-либо параметров, и я не понимаю, можно ли внутри этой концепции организовать загрузку файлов - в данный момент требуется просто передать файл, но, возможно, вместе с ним потребуется передавать какие-либо данные - название, предназначение и т.п. Как это организуется по-человечески?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Немного брейнсторминга.

**Вариант 1**

Закачиваем файл POST-ом, метаданные прикладываем как query-параметры.

```
POST /someurl/upload?date=...&comment=...
```

---

**Вариант 2**

1. Выделяем некий ресурс, описывающий метаданные файла:

   ```
   /someurl/document/{id}
   ```

   и субресурс - непосредственно файл:

   ```
   /someurl/document/{id}/data
   ```
2. Создаем экземпляр, передавая метаданные.

   ```
   POST /someurl/document

   { 
      'date':'2007-03-01T13:00:00Z',
      'comment':'....'
   }
   ```
3. Получаем в ответе идентификатор

   ```
   HTTP/1.1 201 Created

   { 
      'id': 123456,
      'date':'2007-03-01T13:00:00Z',
      'comment':'....'
   }
   ```

   На этом этапе мы уже можем запросить метаданные файла:

   ```
   GET /someurl/document/123456

   HTTP/1.1 200 OK

   { 
      'id': 123456,
      'date':'2007-03-01T13:00:00Z',
      'comment':'....'
   }
   ```

   Но сам файл еще не доступен (субресурс не создан)

   ```
   GET /someurl/document/123456/data

   HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
   ```

   Статус 404 это не страшно, он предполагает, что ресурс еще может появиться по данному пути.
4. Заливаем файл POST-ом как субресурс:

   ```
   POST /someurl/document/123456/data
   ```

   Теперь никаких проблем, файл доступен:

   ```
   GET /someurl/document/123456/data

   HTTP/1.1 200 OK
   ```

---

<sub>Если хочется 100% жирного REST-а с HATEOAS, то на шаге 3 нужно включить в ответ гипертекстовую ссылку на себя и можно избавиться от идентификатора:</sub>

```
{ 
   'date':'2007-03-01T13:00:00Z',
   'comment':'....',
   '_links':{
       'self': { 'href': '/someurl/document/123456' }
   }
}
```

<sub>А после шага 4 по запросу метаданных возвращать и ссылку на файл:</sub>

```
{ 
   'date':'2007-03-01T13:00:00Z',
   'comment':'....',
   '_links':{
       'self': { 'href': '/someurl/document/123456' },
       'data': { 'href': '/someurl/document/123456/data' },
   }
}
```

<sub>Так у клиентской стороны будет меньше соблазна обратиться к еще не загруженному файлу.</sub>

---

**Вариант 3**

Закачиваем все json-ом. Файл пакуем в base64. Сойдет для небольших файлов.

```
POST /someurl/document

{ 
   'date':'2007-03-01T13:00:00Z',
   'comment':'....',
   'file-data':'SGVsbG8gd29ybGRIZWxsbyB3b3JsZEhlbGxvIHdvcmxkSGVsbG8gd29ybGRIZWxsbyB3b3JsZEhlbGxvIHdvcmxkSGVsbG8gd29ybGRIZWxsbyB3b3JsZEhlbGxvIHdvcmxk'  
}
```

---

**Вариант 4**

Используем multipart-запрос. Описание в json и сам файл - две части.

```
POST /someurl/document

Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=spacer


--spacer
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="metadata"
Content-Type: application/json

{ 
   'date':'2007-03-01T13:00:00Z',
   'comment':'....'
}
--spacer
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file-data"
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64

<...байты в base64...>
```

---

Мне импонирует 2й вариант, как наиболее идеологически верный.

Comment: А что будет отдавать сервер между 2 и 4 во втором варианте, если кто-то в этот момент стукнется за данными? Идеологически верным скорее выглядит третий вариант...

Comment: @YuraIvanov, 404, так как субресурс еще не создан

Comment: Пихать файлы в строку, потом прогонять на сервере через json парсер и base64-декодинг?

Comment: Второй вариант гибче, можно на уровне url-ов права рулить, кешировать или файлы через другой сервер заливать-раздавать. Или при миграции хранилища редирект на сам файл вернуть.

Comment: Ну так вы предлагаете создавать какой-то временный битый документ, который как-то должен существовать (id и дата у него есть), при этом отдаваться по 404, какие-то collection.find (в терминах монги, например) должны каким-то причудливом образом не учитывать такие документы. Если 4-й пункт не выполнился (упал канал, бд упала и т.д.), будут битые ссылки. Т.е. нужны какие-то дополнительные методы, проверяющие консистентность базы. Притом если downtime'а нету, то это и вовсе сделать невозможно. Решение в стиле ССЗБ.

Comment: Совершенно нормальная ситуация. Это не временный битый документ, а метаданные документа с пустым телом документа. Если   предметная область ТС (а мы ее не знаем) допускает это, то почему бы нет. Можно, впрочем, спросить @Etki, какой вариант ему подошел.

Comment: Кстати, в варианте №3 придется выделять память сразу под весь файл. В остальных случаях мы можем писать его на диск небольшими кусками по мере вычитывания. Но фломастеры, конечно, имеют разные вкусы, no offence.

Comment: Я просто видел данный подход в других местах, даже какую-то статью про это. Для меня непонятно, зачем для rest'а пользоваться не рестовыми методами. а если нам "надо" грузить файлы, то зачем выделываться. В том смысле, что если мы будем грузить файлы какими-то другими методами нежели через url документа у нас сразу перестанет это быть рестом, ну как бы и ладно...

Comment: На мой вкус все как раз вполне рестово: 1. Явно выделенные ресурсы, с которыми мы работаем. 2. Глаголы HTTP, статусы и `Content-Type` используются строго по назначению. 3. Добавил даже пример с гипермедиа. Уровень 3 по модели зрелости Ричардсона.

Comment: @YuraIvanov все остальные методы, кроме inline base64, рушат концепцию еще больше. "Битый документ" находится по простому `WHERE path IS NULL`.

Answer (score 0):

Еще вариант слать все одним multipart/form-data.
JSON в таком случае нужно сконвертировать в соответствующие ключи FormData.
Из плюсов это конечно же работа с единой сущностью в один момент времени. Атомарность рулит.

И еще один вариант:
Сделать ресурс /upload/tmpfile, который бы помещал файл во временную директорию и возращал бы его id из базы данных (или url, что добавило бы универсальности нашему конечному ресурсу). Дальше можно было бы использовать этот id при отправке обычного JSON-a. 
Минусы все те-же: tmp файлы нужно чистить и появляется дополнительная сущность.