# Разные значения для класса (ресурса), в зависимости от его типа

Tags: веб-программирование, архитектура, проектирование, rest

Делаю REST для сайта. У REST API должен быть ресурс `video`. При обращении на `domain.name/api/videos/` нужно вернуть список всех видео в следующем формате:

```
{
    'title': str,
    'thumbnail': url,
    'video': url
}
```

С этим никаких проблем, само собой, нет.

**Вопрос в следующем:**
для сайта нужно реализовать загрузку (и последующее отображение) видео из:

- youtube
- vimeo
- с компьютера пользователя

Для сохранения нового видео с youtube и vimeo мы можем просто сделать `POST` запрос на `domain.name/api/videos/` с заполненными соответствующими полями (значения которых мы предварительно получили от api youtube и vimeo), а на сервере полученный объект сохранить в базу, проведя только валидацию.

А как быть с пользовательскими видео - теми, которые должны загружаться с компьютера пользователя?
Мыслю следующим образом:
начнем с `thumbnail`. Это картинка. На сколько я понимаю REST, она должна быть отдельным ресурсом, доступным по `domain.name/api/images/`. Значит перед загрузкой видео нам нужно вырезать кадр из видео (или пользователь сам загрузит нужную картинку в форму) и отправить его на сервер - это не проблема. В ответ от `POST => domain.name/api/images/` мы получим:

```
{
    'id': int,
    'src' url
}
```

И здесь самое интересное - на клиент мы отдаем абсолютный url картинки, но в базе на сервере храним путь к ней. То есть при создании ответа делаем что-то вроде `settings.STATIC_BASE + image.path` (это просто псевдокод, чтобы донести мои мысли).
Но в `video` мы не можем просто так взять и передать абсолютный url к картинке на нашем сервере, потому что сегодня у нас `settings.STATIC_BASE == '245.41.20.48/static/'` а завтра он превратится в `http://d111111abcdef8.cloudfront.net` и все загруженные `thumnail'ы` станут недоступны. Верно?
Если верно, то `thumbnail` у `video` должен быть либо:

- `ForeignKey` - в случае пользовательского видео (и пользовательской обложки)
- либо просто строка - если видео "загрузили" с youtube или vimeo

На данный момент ничего из этого не реализовано, поэтому я могу сделать любой необходимый вариант. Меня интересует как это должно быть реализовано с точки зрения:

- архитектуры
- моделей в коде
- ресурсов в rest

Я не жду полностью разжеванного ответа, мне должно помочь и что-нибудь в духе "посмотри как сделано здесь". Сам попытался заглянуть в апи vk.com, fb.com, ok.ru, но у них там все как-то по-разному, поэтому я решил узнать здесь в какую сторону копать.

**UPD:**
Пока больше всего вопросов вызывает как решить проблему с тем, что у модели `Video` поле `thumbnail` должно быть "одновременно" и ForeignKey'ем, ссылающимся на объект `Image`, и простой `строкой`, содержащей ссылку на картинку на стороннем ресурсе

Comment: Почитайте это обсуждение, может быть что-то почерпнете: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/428753

Comment: Спасибо, обсуждение проясняет схему url, вроде мыслю в правильном направлении. Пока больше всего вопросов вызывает как решить проблему с тем, что у модели `Video` поле `thumbnail` должно быть "одновременно" и ForeignKey'ем, ссылающимся на объект `Image`, и простой строкой, содержащей ссылку на картинку на стороннем ресурсе

Comment: Попробую написать мысли по этому поводу вечером. Если коротко:  я бы, вероятно, использовал не FK,  а тоже URL, только не абсолютный, а относительный.

Comment: @Nofate, тогда на клиент придется добавить такой же `settings.STATIC_BASE` и не забывать их синхронно с сервером менять при переезде статики на другой url?  
Впрочем, жду вечера, спасибо за желание помочь.