# Как выглядит json-объект, если одно из его полей - файл?

Tags: java, json, backend

Контроллер бэкэнда принимает объект лекции в виде json

```
@PostMapping
 public ResponseEntity<Lecture> addLecture(@ApiParam(value = "Объект лекции") @RequestBody Lecture lecture) {
        return ResponseEntity.ok(lectureService.addLecture(lecture));
    }
```

Лекция содержит поле, в котором должен передаваться файл лекции

```
    {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Изучение буквы А-а",
    "creationDate": "2020-12-17T09:56:32.604",
    "modificationDate": "2020-12-17T09:56:32.604",
    "description": "А-а",
    "lectureFile": null,
    "testList": []
    }
```

Что должно быть в поле lectureFile, чтобы передать файл? Как поместить туда файл?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Загрузка файла в рамках REST-JSON концепции](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/428753/%d0%97%d0%b0%d0%b3%d1%80%d1%83%d0%b7%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d1%84%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bb%d0%b0-%d0%b2-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%ba%d0%b0%d1%85-rest-json-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bd%d1%86%d0%b5%d0%bf%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%b8)

Answer (score 0):

Поле с файлом выглядит как [base64](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64)

```
{
"id": 1,
"name": "Изучение буквы А-а",
"creationDate": "2020-12-17T09:56:32.604",
"modificationDate": "2020-12-17T09:56:32.604",
"description": "А-а",
"lectureFile": "JVBERi0xLjQKCiXt4f6uCgoyIDAgb2JqCjw8L1R5cGUvWE9iamVjdC9TdWJ0eXBlL0ltYWdlCi9X
                aWR0aCAyNDk2IC9IZWlnaHQgMzQ2NAovQ29sb3JTcGFjZS9EZXZpY2VSR0IKL0JpdHNQZXJDb21w
                b25lbnQgOAovTGVuZ3RoIDY1MTQzNgovRmlsdGVyL0RDVERlY29kZQo+PgpzdHJlYW0K/9j/4AAQ
                SkZJRgABAQEBLAEsAAD//gAZQCgjKSBHZW5lcmF0ZWQgYnkgVEorKwD/2wBDABcREA4RFBQSFBci
                GxcYGiIfHyIlOUhSOSk1MkZmW05QSFFVV05ifGFbb4OHfHObclBYkpSSi5+soG2Dqo6Sj43/2wBD
                ARgaGiIeIkMlJUONXlBejY2NjY2NjY2NjY2NjY2NjY2NjY2NjY2NjY2NjY2NjY2NjY2NjY2NjY2N
                jY2NjY2NjY3/wAARCA2ICcADASEAAhEBAxEB/8QAHwAAAQUBAQEBAQEAAAAAAAAAAAECAwQFBgcI
                CQoL/8QAtRAAAgEDAwIEAwUFBAQAAAF9AQIDAAQRBRIhMUEGE1FhByJxFDKBkaEII0KxwRVS0fAk
                M2JyggkKFhcYGRolJicoKSo0NTY3ODk6Q0RFRkdISUpTVFVWV1hZWmNkZWZnaGlqc3R1dnd4eXqD
                hIWGh4iJipKTlJWWl5iZmqKjpKWmp6ipqrKztLW2t7i5usLDxMXGx8jJytLT1NXW19jZ2uHi4+Tl",
"testList": []
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Обычно файлы хранят отдельно на облаке, а передают метаданные